# Some integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I've come across the need to solve the following integral

$$\int\cos^{-1}(a \tan x)\cos x\ dx$$

Wolfram gives a solution, but I'd like to know how to integrate this. I really have no idea how to start.

Comment: by $cos^{-1}$ you mean $arccos$ function or just $\frac{1}{cos}$?

Comment: @Tomas $\cos^{-1}$ is well known to be an equivalent notation for $\arccos$.

Comment: @FlybyNight I know, I just wanted to make sure, that we're on the same page.

Comment: @Tomas You knew what was meant.

Comment: @FlybyNight So what? $cos^{-1}$ notation is not so widespread as you might think. There are traditions to use arccos instead.

Comment: @Tomas So you admit that you knew what was meant! The notation $\cos^{-1}$ is not *used* always, but it is *known* to almost everyone. Most of us started off using $\cos^{-1}$ (because that's what is on most calculators). It's only later in life that we change to $\arccos$. Asking for clarification of something that is clear, and you know is clear, is a waste of time.

Comment: @FlybyNight No, I wasn't completely sure about which meaning is meant. That is why I asked. And in my country we started with arccos, arcsin, arctg, arcctg functions since early days when we leared about these functions in schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integration by parts to get $$I=\int\cos^{-1}(a\tan x)\cos x dx=\sin x\cos^{-1}(a\tan x)+\int \frac{a\sec^2x}{\sqrt{1-a^2\tan^2x}}\sin x dx\\=\sin x\cos^{-1}(a\tan x)+\int \frac{a\sec x\tan x }{\sqrt{1-a^2\sec^2x+a^2}}dx$$ Now, to evaluate the second integration, put $z=\sec x$ and get the integral $$\int a\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+a^2-a^2z^2}}$$. Hope, you can proceed from here to get the final result.

Comment: @user137794 Just want to point out here that $\sin x\sec^2x=\sec x\tan x$.  Thought this might clarify his choice of substitution.

Comment: @Mike that is why I used that particular substitution. Anyway I will update that in my answer, thanks.